# Name of Semantic Relationship: "has-instance" / "is-instance-of"

Tags: grammar, semantics, linguistics

I am looking for the name of the semantic relationship "has-instance".
For example: "swimmer" - "Michael Phelps". What is the correct name of this relationship?

And further: What is the name of the reversed relationship (is-instance-of)?

Comment: Not a great example if you have to use a person's name.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Feel free to edit the question and pick a better example if you have one.

Comment: I've never seen "has-instance". Is it something to do with programming? Also, if you've got an example of 'is-instance-of' handy it might be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  It's not very clear.  But I'm going to take a stab in the dark.  Maybe you're looking for "correlation" or "corollary."  Or maybe you're just looking for the word "example," but you use that word in your question, so I dunno.

Comment: I don't know how as I don't understand the question. Are you looking for "key words"?

Comment: Looks to me like ***categorization, categorizing, classification***. Or maybe ***exemplification*** (in the specific sub-sense defined by the full OED as ***The citing of illustrative examples; an illustrative example***). You could coin a nonce-word such as ***hierarchicalization***, but I doubt there's any existing term with that *precise* implication (of everything either being contained within some parent set, or of being a parent set containing children / examples itself).

Comment: I am looking for a linguistic term such as: Hypernymy, hyponymy, pertainymy, meronymy, holonymy, or troponymy.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Yes you find this very often in programming or (IT) knowledge management systems. However, I am interested whether there is also a linguistic name for this relation between a concept and an instance (independent of the IT context).

Comment: @Janothan. Thanks. If none of FumbleFingers' suggestions appeal to you I think we need a really straightforward example; without the words 'has-instance' or 'is-instance-of', which don't mean anything to me. The relationship between 'swimmer' and 'Phelps' is simply that of a category and a member of that category. Maybe you could *define* the linguistic term you want we could help you. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: Member of a set?